# Subdifferential of $f(x,y)=|x|+|y|$

Tags: analysis

Today I learnt about the subdifferential and the example $g(x)=|x|$, but I have problems in higher dimensions. I plotted $f(x)$, but I don't know which vectors  are the subgradients exactly, because I don't know how to use the formula in this example. Can someone explain that to me? Or is there a way to plot the subdifferentials as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In all my years of studying math, I've never come across this topic. Can you provide the worked example for $|x|$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams This is a standard topic in convex optimization. You can read the definition and the example $f(x)=|x|$ on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative).